# is there any way to have persistence per user in a "DI scope" both through "http request" and in blazor components via DI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, blazor, blazor-server-side

I usually used "Windows Authentication" and always had an HTTPContext with logged user information.

I observed that "PerScope" DI not always preserved, especially when requesting a "Per Scope" service into a Blazor Component (Blazor-server).

I solved this by creating a singleton with a Dictionary of Scopes cached by user name.

```
    public class PerUserPersistentScopeService
            {
                private readonly MemoryCache _usersCache;
                private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
                
                public PerUserPersistentScopeService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
                {
                    _serviceScopeFactory = scopeFactory;
                    _usersCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions(){ExpirationScanFrequency = new TimeSpan(0,5,0)});
                }
...
               public T GetService<T>(){
                  using here httpcontext.user.identity.name to obtain
                         a per use service
               }
```

With this singleton I always got a GetService  per user scope.

**BUT**

Now, IIS Server (Not IIS Express) doesn't return the user identity in the HTTPContext under windows authentication when I use Blazor Components (server-side).

Some components are so generic (Example: Navigation panel, etc...) and others so specific that Cascading so many complex per user entities are not practical.

Is there a way to get a general Scoped DI back working on both blazor pages and components?

Or it would also work ...

Is there any other way to obtain (without cascading parameters) the name of the user to whom a blazor component or a blazor page is served?

Comment: Lack of a real example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a Serializable ContextIdentity Class
   (The class must have an empty constructor)

`[Serializable]
    public class ContextIdentity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string AuthenticationType { get; set; }
        public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        public string Account { get; set; } 
        public ContextIdentity()
        {
        }
        public ContextIdentity(string name, string 
            authenticationType, bool isAuthenticated)
        {
            Name = name;
            AuthenticationType = authenticationType;
            IsAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
            if (isAuthenticated)
            {
                var sp = Name.Split('\\');
                if (sp.Length == 2)
                {
                    Domain = sp[0];
                    Account = sp[1];
                }
                else
                {
                    Domain = "";
                    Account = Name;
                }
            }
        }
        public ContextIdentity(IIdentity identity):
            this(identity?.Name,identity?.AuthenticationType,
                identity?.IsAuthenticated??false)
        {
        }
    }`

2. Create a scoped service called ContextIdentityProvider

`public class ContextIdentityProvider
    {
        public ContextIdentity Identity { get; set; }
    }`

3. Edit App.razor to inject identity

`@inject ContextIdentityProvider contextIdentityProvider
&lt;CascadingAuthenticationState&gt;
    &lt;Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" 
    PreferExactMatches="@true"&gt;
    &lt;Found Context="routeData"&gt;
    &lt;AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" 
    DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" /&gt;
    &lt;/Found&gt;
    &lt;NotFound&gt;
        &lt;LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)"&gt;
            &lt;p&gt;Sorry, there's nothing at this 
            address.&lt;/p&gt;
        &lt;/LayoutView&gt;
    &lt;/NotFound&gt;
    &lt;/Router&gt;
&lt;/CascadingAuthenticationState&gt;
@code{
    &#91;Parameter&#93;
    public ContextIdentity ContextIdentity { get; set; }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        contextIdentityProvider.Identity = ContextIdentity;
    }
}`

4. To persist ContextIdentity across different tabs to same use, create a SINGLETON repository service of SCOPEs for same user.

`public class PerUserPersistentScopeService
    {
        private readonly MemoryCache _usersCache;
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
        public PerUserPersistentScopeService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
        {
            _serviceScopeFactory = scopeFactory;
            _usersCache = new MemoryCache(
                new MemoryCacheOptions(){
                    ExpirationScanFrequency = new TimeSpan(0,5,0)
                    });
        }
        public IServiceProvider GetProvider(ContextIdentity identity)
        {
            if (identity is null) return null;
            if (!identity.IsAuthenticated) return null;
            var serviceScope = _usersCache.GetOrCreate(identity.Name, entry =>
            {
                entry.SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);
                var e=_serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
                var newidentity = 
                     e.ServiceProvider.GetService();
                newidentity.Identity = identity;
                return e;
            });
            return serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
        }
        public T GetService(ContextIdentity identity) where T:class
        {
            var p = GetProvider(identity);
            if (p is null) return null;
            return p.GetService();
        }
    }`

**NOTE**: When create a new scope service provider, you must  reinject the contextidentity to the new scope.